# JNI NoClassDefFoundError while executing method in injected jar

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am getting `NoClassDefFoundError` when trying to inject a jar file into a running java process.

Jar file bytes:

```cpp
static const unsigned char lib_bytes[] = {
        0x50, 0x4b, 0x03, 0x04, 0x14, 0x00, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x00, 0x03, 0x9a, 0x57, 0x57, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x14, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x4d, 0x45, 0x54, 0x41, 0x2d, 0x49, 0x4e, 0x46, 0x2f, 0x4d, 0x41, 0x4e, 0x49, 0x46, 0x45, 0x53, 0x54, 0x2e, 0x4d, 0x46, 0xfe, 0xca, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7d, 0x52, 0xcb, 0x6e, 0xe3, 0x30, 0x0c, 0xbc, 0x07, 0xc8, 0x3f, 0xf8, 0x07, 0x28, 0xf8, 0x15, 0xa7, 0xee, 0x75, 0x81, 0xbd, 0x15, 0xe8, 0xa9, 0xd7, 0x85, 0xe2, 0x28, 0x36, 0x0d, 0x59, 0x32, 0x24, 0x3a, 0xde, 0xfc, 0xfd, 0x52, 0xb2, 0xf3, 0x30, 0x5a, 0x2c, 0x72, 0xb1, 0xc8, 0x99, 0xe1, 0x70, 0xc2, 0x0f, 0x69, 0xf0, 0xa2, 0x3c, 0xc1, 0x97, 0x72, 0x1e, 0xad, 0x79, 0x4f, 0x32, 0x91, 0xee, 0x77, 0xbf, 0xb4, 0xf4, 0x1e, 0x3e, 0x25, 0x75, 0xef, 0x89, 0xf4, 0x03, 0xd4, 0xa2, 0x14, 0xbd, 0x74, 0x49, 0x6f, 0x24, 0x14, 0xfc, 0x9d, 0xc6, 0xd7, 0x07, 0x1a, 0xd5, 0x38, 0x79, 0xa1, 0xf8, 0x32, 0x8a, 0xe8, 0x06, 0x99, 0xa8, 0xe2, 0xab, 0xf5, 0xd6, 0x40, 0xbe, 0xdf, 0x25, 0x22, 0x5f, 0xb9, 0xed, 0x24, 0xaf, 0x12, 0xb2, 0xe3, 0x4a, 0xa6, 0x19, 0xa9, 0xe9, 0xa0, 0x12, 0x87, 0x45, 0x19, 0xcd, 0x38, 0x11, 0xe4, 0xdc, 0x5d, 0x0b, 0x13, 0xa1, 0xf6, 0xac, 0x97, 0x46, 0x02, 0x2b, 0xb9, 0xc4, 0xfa, 0x0e, 0xa1, 0xb1, 0x4e, 0x71, 0x39, 0x8b, 0x28, 0xa7, 0xa4, 0x1e, 0x02, 0xea, 0x28, 0x8a, 0x3a, 0x56, 0xe4, 0x44, 0x9d, 0xc6, 0x13, 0x97, 0x0e, 0x22, 0x5f, 0x40, 0x8d, 0x1d, 0x06, 0x6b, 0x3c, 0xa0, 0x65, 0xfd, 0x32, 0x78, 0x0a, 0xd5, 0x8e, 0x68, 0x8c, 0x5a, 0xa5, 0x28, 0xd8, 0x64, 0x28, 0x8d, 0x5a, 0xd2, 0xc5, 0xba, 0xe1, 0x65, 0xc7, 0xde, 0x8e, 0x04, 0x1e, 0x87, 0x51, 0x07, 0x60, 0xf5, 0x64, 0x6a, 0x54, 0xac, 0x64, 0x28, 0xd2, 0x8b, 0x75, 0xce, 0x59, 0x35, 0xb3, 0xbc, 0x42, 0x9e, 0x66, 0xfc, 0xcb, 0x8b, 0xcd, 0xf4, 0xd8, 0x65, 0x5b, 0xf5, 0xa6, 0xaa, 0xa5, 0x69, 0x0b, 0x60, 0xa5, 0xe2, 0xe1, 0x42, 0xdb, 0xb6, 0xec, 0x41, 0x8e, 0x18, 0xd2, 0x80, 0x93, 0x22, 0x59, 0x3f, 0xe5, 0x7b, 0xeb, 0x4e, 0xe8, 0xb7, 0x13, 0x16, 0x42, 0xdc, 0x25, 0x26, 0xfe, 0x4a, 0xf2, 0x76, 0x32, 0x67, 0x7f, 0xf3, 0xa4, 0x86, 0x40, 0x0a, 0xbc, 0xe3, 0xd6, 0x80, 0x6d, 0x5b, 0x34, 0x6d, 0x4c, 0x74, 0x63, 0x98, 0x95, 0x58, 0x73, 0x18, 0x9d, 0xf2, 0x21, 0xe0, 0xb7, 0x35, 0x71, 0x6c, 0xa6, 0xfb, 0xb0, 0xc1, 0xf6, 0xec, 0x1e, 0x0e, 0xd9, 0x6a, 0x7c, 0xb9, 0x00, 0xa9, 0x35, 0x84, 0xf4, 0xd8, 0xdc, 0x6f, 0x34, 0x52, 0x8b, 0x9e, 0x95, 0x82, 0x4b, 0x3c, 0x39, 0xe9, 0x6e, 0x3d, 0x5f, 0x41, 0x34, 0xb5, 0xec, 0x90, 0xdd, 0x77, 0x58, 0xba, 0x7a, 0xee, 0x5b, 0x6d, 0x47, 0xc5, 0xbc, 0xd8, 0x4f, 0xdf, 0xf2, 0xe5, 0x7a, 0x62, 0x23, 0xe4, 0x94, 0x73, 0x80, 0x25, 0x18, 0x6c, 0x3b, 0xd2, 0xb7, 0x80, 0x39, 0xa4, 0x79, 0x5a, 0x3f, 0x31, 0x7f, 0xc2, 0xdd, 0xc0, 0x7f, 0x50, 0xcb, 0xa5, 0x85, 0xed, 0x1e, 0x7f, 0x77, 0xbc, 0x3a, 0x30, 0x92, 0xf0, 0xaa, 0x3c, 0xcc, 0x68, 0xce, 0x76, 0xf6, 0xaf, 0x57, 0xfa, 0x40, 0x56, 0xdf, 0x71, 0x41, 0xa9, 0x2a, 0x5f, 0xd1, 0xea, 0x2f, 0x29, 0x17, 0x36, 0x78, 0xd0, 0xca, 0xef, 0xb4, 0x3b, 0x67, 0x59, 0x2c, 0x22, 0x59, 0x69, 0x71, 0xf3, 0x93, 0xf7, 0x9f, 0xec, 0xed, 0x77, 0xfb, 0xdd, 0x3f, 0x50, 0x4b, 0x07, 0x08, 0x61, 0xd5, 0x4a, 0x60, 0xc0, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc2, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x50, 0x4b, 0x03, 0x04, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x9a, 0x57, 0x57, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4d, 0x45, 0x54, 0x41, 0x2d, 0x49, 0x4e, 0x46, 0x2f, 0x50, 0x4b, 0x03, 0x04, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x9a, 0x57, 0x57, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x2f, 0x50, 0x4b, 0x03, 0x04, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x9a, 0x57, 0x57, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x2f, 0x7a, 0x65, 0x64, 0x69, 0x6b, 0x2f, 0x50, 0x4b, 0x03, 0x04, 0x14, 0x00, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x00, 0xe4, 0x99, 0x57, 0x57, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x21, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x2f, 0x7a, 0x65, 0x64, 0x69, 0x6b, 0x2f, 0x48, 0x61, 0x63, 0x6b, 0x43, 0x6c, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x50, 0x61, 0x74, 0x63, 0x68, 0x65, 0x72, 0x24, 0x31, 0x2e, 0x63, 0x6c, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x8d, 0x53, 0x6d, 0x4f, 0x13, 0x41, 0x10, 0x7e, 0x96, 0x1e, 0x3d, 0x28, 0x07, 0xc5, 0x62, 0x95, 0x5a, 0xd0, 0x8a, 0x55, 0xdb, 0x5a, 0x38, 0x4e, 0xf1, 0xb5, 0x84, 0x0f, 0x10, 0x0c, 0x24, 0x05, 0x4c, 0x30, 0x4d, 0x94, 0x4f, 0xdb, 0x63, 0x53, 0x0e, 0xda, 0xbb, 0x7a, 0xb7, 0xad, 0xc6, 0x7f, 0xe2, 0x17, 0x7f, 0x03, 0x26, 0x06, 0x12, 0x4d, 0xfc, 0x01, 0xfe, 0x28, 0xe3, 0xdc, 0x5e, 0x23, 0x01, 0x6a, 0xf5, 0x2e, 0xd9, 0x9d, 0x9d, 0x9d, 0x79, 0x66, 0x9e, 0x99, 0xd9, 0x9f, 0xbf, 0xbe, 0xfd, 0x00, 0xb0, 0x8c, 0x4a, 0x02, 0x43, 0x88, 0xe9, 0xd0, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x23, 0xce, 0x70, 0xd3, 0xf3, 0x1b, 0xa6, 0x57, 0x3f, 0x14, 0xb6, 0x7c, 0x2f, 0xea, 0x26, 0x0f, 0x5a, 0xe6, 0x5a, 0x93, 0x07, 0x41, 0xcd, 0x09, 0x1c, 0xe9, 0xf9, 0x0c, 0xf1, 0x65, 0xc7, 0x75, 0xe4, 0x0a, 0x43, 0xbe, 0xb0, 0x59, 0x1d, 0x6c, 0x5c, 0x29, 0xd6, 0x46, 0x30, 0xc2, 0x60, 0x34, 0x84, 0xdc, 0xf2, 0x3a, 0x81, 0xd8, 0xe9, 0x0a, 0x3f, 0x81, 0x04, 0xc6, 0x74, 0x18, 0x06, 0xc6, 0x31, 0xc1, 0x30, 0x79, 0xc8, 0xbb, 0xdc, 0x6c, 0x72, 0xb7, 0x61, 0xee, 0x4a, 0xdf, 0x71, 0x1b, 0x14, 0x41, 0xbc, 0xeb, 0xf0, 0x66, 0xc0, 0x90, 0x2e, 0x54, 0xcf, 0x6e, 0x77, 0x54, 0x98, 0x4a, 0xf1, 0xad, 0x8e, 0x49, 0x86, 0xd9, 0x96, 0x30, 0x3f, 0x8a, 0x7d, 0xe7, 0xc8, 0xdc, 0xe0, 0xf6, 0x91, 0x0a, 0xfa, 0x8a, 0x4b, 0xfb, 0x40, 0xf8, 0x79, 0x2b, 0x6f, 0xe9, 0x48, 0x31, 0x64, 0x2e, 0x27, 0xb7, 0xd3, 0xb6, 0xbd, 0x7d, 0x11, 0xc4, 0x88, 0x2a, 0x46, 0x91, 0xc6, 0x35, 0x1d, 0xd7, 0x0d, 0x4c, 0x23, 0xc3, 0x90, 0x1d, 0x00, 0xc8, 0x30, 0x64, 0x77, 0x19, 0x72, 0xff, 0xa2, 0x1b, 0x96, 0x32, 0x6b, 0x60, 0x06, 0xb3, 0x0c, 0x63, 0xdd, 0x50, 0xb9, 0x25, 0xe4, 0x81, 0xb7, 0xcf, 0xd0, 0xa2, 0x5a, 0x5d, 0x24, 0x5a, 0xf9, 0x1f, 0xcd, 0xde, 0x65, 0x55, 0xb1, 0x4f, 0x1a, 0x51, 0x9c, 0xb3, 0x3c, 0x92, 0xb8, 0x15, 0xf6, 0x33, 0xc7, 0xb0, 0x5a, 0xa8, 0x0e, 0x60, 0x56, 0xe9, 0xd7, 0xc2, 0xf3, 0x60, 0xc5, 0x1a, 0x83, 0xb6, 0x46, 0x65, 0x63, 0x48, 0x56, 0x1d, 0x57, 0x6c, 0x77, 0x5a, 0x75, 0xe1, 0xbf, 0xe6, 0xf5, 0x26, 0x69, 0x52, 0x55, 0xcf, 0xe6, 0xcd, 0x1a, 0xf7, 0x9d, 0xf0, 0xdc, 0x53, 0x6a, 0xf2, 0xc0, 0xa1, 0xee, 0xcd, 0x0e, 0x0c, 0x4c, 0x66, 0xdc, 0x6f, 0x2c, 0x32, 0xb0, 0xcd, 0x48, 0xa4, 0x2a, 0xc7, 0xb9, 0x6d, 0x8b, 0x80, 0x5c, 0x35, 0x97, 0xb7, 0x14, 0xfa, 0x25, 0xf2, 0x0c, 0x09, 0x6a, 0xa0, 0xed, 0x3b, 0x6d, 0x35, 0x8c, 0xa3, 0x81, 0xd3, 0x70, 0xb9, 0xec, 0xf8, 0x64, 0x9d, 0x10, 0x1f, 0x6c, 0xd1, 0x96, 0x8e, 0xe7, 0x12, 0xc2, 0x54, 0x9f, 0xc2, 0x31, 0x8c, 0xef, 0x4a, 0xca, 0x64, 0x8b, 0xb7, 0x7b, 0x99, 0x26, 0x76, 0xbd, 0x8e, 0x6f, 0x8b, 0x97, 0x4e, 0x78, 0x48, 0x5f, 0xcc, 0x72, 0x21, 0x44, 0x20, 0xd6, 0xeb, 0xae, 0xdd, 0xf4, 0x02, 0x42, 0x88, 0x0a, 0xa3, 0xe3, 0x31, 0x0d, 0xd7, 0x5f, 0xb9, 0x19, 0x78, 0x8a, 0x67, 0x34, 0xf3, 0xed, 0xf0, 0xa8, 0x2e, 0x04, 0xe5, 0x33, 0x5d, 0xd8, 0x5b, 0xed, 0xd3, 0xca, 0xbd, 0x55, 0x86, 0x91, 0x6d, 0x11, 0xc8, 0x0d, 0x2f, 0x90, 0xe4, 0xb4, 0xe9, 0xba, 0xc2, 0xef, 0x39, 0x21, 0x47, 0x13, 0x3a, 0x84, 0xf0, 0x0b, 0x57, 0x7a, 0x9d, 0x60, 0xb8, 0x4d, 0xd2, 0x3a, 0x62, 0xf4, 0x03, 0x7a, 0x29, 0x5b, 0x3e, 0x05, 0xfb, 0xa2, 0x0c, 0xe6, 0x68, 0x0d, 0x0d, 0x40, 0xcf, 0xea, 0x0e, 0xad, 0xb9, 0xc8, 0x04, 0x79, 0xdc, 0x55, 0x10, 0x3a, 0xee, 0xe1, 0xbe, 0xba, 0xd7, 0x51, 0x40, 0x86, 0x3c, 0x58, 0x38, 0xa8, 0x3d, 0xc8, 0xcf, 0xf4, 0x28, 0xe3, 0xb4, 0x5b, 0xe5, 0x94, 0x7e, 0x82, 0xd1, 0x4f, 0x98, 0xf9, 0x8e, 0xe4, 0x9b, 0x52, 0x6a, 0xaa, 0xf4, 0x15, 0x57, 0xb3, 0xe5, 0xf9, 0x8c, 0x96, 0x19, 0x3e, 0xc1, 0x8d, 0x53, 0xdc, 0x3c, 0x3e, 0xaf, 0x39, 0x26, 0xa7, 0x98, 0x0a, 0x3e, 0xa1, 0x02, 0x4e, 0xd2, 0xbb, 0xba, 0x42, 0xe7, 0x19, 0x95, 0xc4, 0x4a, 0x04, 0xfa, 0x27, 0x09, 0x0b, 0xc5, 0x5e, 0x12, 0x16, 0x4a, 0x78, 0xa0, 0x78, 0x59, 0x28, 0x93, 0x14, 0x53, 0xd2, 0x3c, 0x49, 0x9a, 0x92, 0x16, 0x60, 0x12, 0xe3, 0x45, 0x85, 0xce, 0xe6, 0x48, 0x69, 0x29, 0x96, 0x0f, 0xf1, 0x88, 0x76, 0x0d, 0x4b, 0x78, 0x82, 0xe7, 0x4a, 0xb3, 0x84, 0x17, 0xb4, 0xa7, 0x48, 0x4a, 0x23, 0xfa, 0x92, 0xd1, 0xf6, 0x1b, 0x50, 0x4b, 0x07, 0x08, 0xaf, 0xf7, 0x86, 0xbd, 0x86, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0xe2, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x50, 0x4b, 0x03, 0x04, 0x14, 0x00, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x00, 0xe4, 0x99, 0x57, 0x57, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x23, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x2f, 0x7a, 0x65, 0x64, 0x69, 0x6b, 0x2f, 0x48, 0x61, 0x63, 0x6b, 0x43, 0x6c, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x50, 0x61, 0x74, 0x63, 0x68, 0x65, 0x72, 0x24, 0x31, 0x24, 0x31, 0x2e, 0x63, 0x6c, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x8d, 0x53, 0x5d, 0x4f, 0x13, 0x41, 0x14, 0x3d, 0xb7, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x94, 0x2d, 0xd4, 0x42, 0x95, 0x0a, 0x08, 0xd4, 0xa2, 0xfd, 0xa0, 0x2c, 0xf5, 0xf3, 0x01, 0x62, 0x8c, 0x80, 0xa1, 0x49, 0x41, 0x13, 0x48, 0x5f, 0x7c, 0x9a, 0x6e, 0x27, 0xed, 0x42, 0xbb, 0x6b, 0x76, 0xb7, 0x35, 0xf1, 0x8f, 0x18, 0xfd, 0x17, 0x26, 0x8a, 0x89, 0x0f, 0x46, 0x5f, 0xfd, 0x51, 0xc6, 0x3b, 0xb3, 0x44, 0x12, 0x88, 0x85, 0x49, 0x76, 0x66, 0xf6, 0xce, 0x9d, 0x73, 0xce, 0xfd, 0x98, 0xdf, 0x7f, 0xbe, 0xff, 0x00, 0xb0, 0x85, 0xa7, 0x13, 0x88, 0x20, 0x9a, 0x40, 0xcc, 0xc0, 0x18, 0xe2, 0x84, 0xc5, 0xbe, 0x34, 0xdf, 0xcb, 0xb6, 0x7d, 0x62, 0xee, 0x09, 0xeb, 0x64, 0xbb, 0x27, 0x7c, 0xff, 0xb5, 0x08, 0xac, 0xae, 0xf4, 0x0a, 0xb5, 0x42, 0x8d, 0x10, 0x0f, 0xba, 0xb6, 0x5f, 0xd8, 0x60, 0xc7, 0xc6, 0x08, 0xcf, 0xcd, 0x24, 0xc6, 0x31, 0x91, 0x40, 0xd2, 0xc0, 0x24, 0x0c, 0xc2, 0x92, 0xeb, 0x75, 0x4c, 0xb7, 0x75, 0x2c, 0xad, 0xe0, 0x9d, 0x6c, 0x99, 0xc2, 0xef, 0x9b, 0xfb, 0x32, 0xe8, 0xba, 0xed, 0xa6, 0xed, 0xdb, 0x81, 0xeb, 0x31, 0xee, 0x96, 0xed, 0xd8, 0xc1, 0x33, 0xc2, 0x6a, 0xb1, 0xde, 0xb8, 0xc2, 0x7b, 0xb3, 0xd4, 0x4c, 0x60, 0x8a, 0x90, 0x3e, 0x16, 0x43, 0x61, 0xf6, 0x84, 0xd3, 0x31, 0x77, 0xdc, 0x41, 0xab, 0x27, 0x93, 0x48, 0x21, 0x6d, 0xe0, 0x06, 0x32, 0x84, 0xc9, 0xb6, 0x36, 0x35, 0x45, 0x6f, 0x20, 0x09, 0xd1, 0x62, 0x69, 0x27, 0xfe, 0x7c, 0x1c, 0x7a, 0xa8, 0x90, 0x6f, 0x1a, 0xb8, 0x85, 0x39, 0x42, 0xa4, 0x3f, 0x24, 0xac, 0x5c, 0xc9, 0xa8, 0xe2, 0xb9, 0x6d, 0x60, 0x1e, 0x0b, 0x04, 0x63, 0xa8, 0x8c, 0x8d, 0xb6, 0x55, 0x77, 0x7c, 0x87, 0x90, 0x2d, 0x36, 0xce, 0x75, 0xbc, 0xd2, 0x18, 0x2c, 0x90, 0xf0, 0xa2, 0x38, 0x32, 0x43, 0xd7, 0x89, 0x92, 0x10, 0xdb, 0x76, 0xdb, 0x2c, 0x7f, 0xba, 0x61, 0x3b, 0xf2, 0x60, 0xd0, 0x6f, 0x49, 0xef, 0x48, 0x70, 0x54, 0x84, 0x4c, 0xc3, 0xb5, 0x44, 0xaf, 0x29, 0x3c, 0x5b, 0xfd, 0x9f, 0x19, 0x63, 0xaa, 0x38, 0x9c, 0xed, 0x51, 0xc4, 0x4c, 0xcd, 0x8e, 0xc2, 0xeb, 0x70, 0x0d, 0xa9, 0x1e, 0x6e, 0xb9, 0xae, 0xd1, 0xa1, 0xf0, 0x14, 0xea, 0xc5, 0x94, 0xb2, 0xf3, 0xd8, 0x30, 0xcc, 0x61, 0xe6, 0x72, 0x9c, 0x84, 0xd4, 0x61, 0xc0, 0x14, 0xfb, 0xe2, 0xed, 0x99, 0x84, 0xe4, 0xa1, 0x3b, 0xf0, 0x2c, 0xf9, 0xd2, 0x56, 0x3f, 0xd9, 0x8b, 0xf4, 0xeb, 0x0a, 0x81, 0xc3, 0xd9, 0x75, 0xac, 0x9e, 0xeb, 0xdb, 0x4e, 0x27, 0x8c, 0x38, 0x01, 0x93, 0x30, 0x3f, 0x42, 0xb4, 0x81, 0x1a, 0x1e, 0x70, 0x4d, 0x75, 0xe6, 0xc3, 0x3b, 0x84, 0x3e, 0x77, 0xca, 0xb9, 0xa2, 0xc3, 0xc0, 0x63, 0xbc, 0xcd, 0xeb, 0x58, 0xde, 0x5c, 0x36, 0x95, 0xae, 0xac, 0x06, 0x61, 0xfc, 0x40, 0xfa, 0xc1, 0x9e, 0xeb, 0x07, 0x09, 0x3c, 0x26, 0xe4, 0xfe, 0x2b, 0x97, 0x3b, 0xa4, 0xee, 0x38, 0xd2, 0xd3, 0x36, 0xe9, 0x63, 0x99, 0xdb, 0x4d, 0x75, 0x1e, 0xa5, 0xd3, 0xea, 0x8d, 0xf1, 0x2e, 0xc2, 0xdf, 0x24, 0x16, 0x41, 0xb8, 0xc3, 0xbb, 0x23, 0x44, 0x11, 0xe3, 0xd5, 0x28, 0x57, 0xbe, 0x82, 0xca, 0x0b, 0xd5, 0x6f, 0x48, 0x7c, 0xd6, 0x5e, 0x4b, 0x3c, 0xc7, 0xd9, 0x0b, 0xdc, 0xd2, 0xcb, 0x3c, 0x97, 0x43, 0x3f, 0xac, 0x20, 0xaf, 0x1b, 0x59, 0xbf, 0x59, 0x7d, 0x6e, 0xe0, 0x2e, 0x0a, 0x1a, 0xd7, 0xc0, 0x2a, 0xe6, 0x18, 0x91, 0x54, 0xb3, 0x9e, 0x31, 0x0c, 0xf8, 0x9e, 0xba, 0x99, 0xaf, 0x1c, 0x54, 0x7f, 0x21, 0xf5, 0x11, 0x33, 0xd5, 0x9f, 0x48, 0xed, 0xaf, 0x9d, 0x62, 0x7a, 0x16, 0x33, 0x1f, 0x3e, 0x21, 0x5a, 0xfe, 0x82, 0x6c, 0xe5, 0x14, 0x39, 0xc5, 0x1b, 0xd5, 0xbc, 0x19, 0x7d, 0x63, 0x16, 0x53, 0xc8, 0x22, 0xc7, 0x88, 0x2b, 0x3c, 0x2b, 0x0d, 0xcb, 0x7c, 0x3e, 0xc5, 0xea, 0xef, 0xe1, 0xbe, 0xe6, 0xcb, 0xff, 0x53, 0x93, 0x47, 0x11, 0x25, 0x66, 0x2c, 0x6b, 0x0c, 0xca, 0x31, 0x40, 0x45, 0x87, 0xb1, 0x86, 0x2a, 0xaf, 0x31, 0xac, 0x63, 0x03, 0x0f, 0xb5, 0xe5, 0x11, 0x9e, 0x68, 0x8a, 0x08, 0xdb, 0xc2, 0x11, 0x09, 0x97, 0xbf, 0x50, 0x4b, 0x07, 0x08, 0xcd, 0x1d, 0x0f, 0xa0, 0x58, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x98, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x50, 0x4b, 0x03, 0x04, 0x14, 0x00, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x00, 0xe4, 0x99, 0x57, 0x57, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x2f, 0x7a, 0x65, 0x64, 0x69, 0x6b, 0x2f, 0x48, 0x61, 0x63, 0x6b, 0x43, 0x6c, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x50, 0x61, 0x74, 0x63, 0x68, 0x65, 0x72, 0x2e, 0x63, 0x6c, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x95, 0x54, 0xeb, 0x52, 0xd3, 0x40, 0x18, 0x3d, 0x4b, 0x0b, 0xa1, 0x25, 0x08, 0x22, 0x20, 0x88, 0x5c, 0x05, 0x6d, 0x2b, 0x10, 0x50, 0xbc, 0x51, 0x44, 0xa1, 0x82, 0x54, 0x4b, 0x41, 0x61, 0x70, 0x90, 0x5f, 0xdb, 0x74, 0x81, 0x40, 0x48, 0x3a, 0xe9, 0x22, 0xd6, 0x67, 0xf0, 0x61, 0x74, 0x06, 0xc1, 0x91, 0x19, 0x1f, 0xc0, 0x87, 0x72, 0xfc, 0x36, 0xe1, 0x36, 0x60, 0x41, 0x33, 0x93, 0xec, 0x25, 0xdf, 0x39, 0xdf, 0xf9, 0x2e, 0xbb, 0xbf, 0x7e, 0xff, 0xf8, 0x09, 0x60, 0x0c, 0x6f, 0xa2, 0xa8, 0x40, 0x48, 0x43, 0x58, 0x47, 0x25, 0xaa, 0x18, 0xea, 0x37, 0xf8, 0x07, 0x6e, 0xd8, 0xdc, 0x59, 0x33, 0xe6, 0x72, 0x1b, 0xc2, 0x94, 0x0c, 0x55, 0x63, 0x96, 0x63, 0xc9, 0x71, 0x86, 0x50, 0x2c, 0xbe, 0x14, 0x45, 0x35, 0x22, 0x1a, 0xa2, 0x3a, 0x6a, 0xa0, 0x33, 0x74, 0x38, 0x42, 0x1a, 0x5b, 0x96, 0x23, 0x4c, 0x8f, 0xaf, 0x4a, 0xc3, 0xb4, 0x2d, 0xe1, 0x48, 0x63, 0xf6, 0x68, 0x83, 0x41, 0x5f, 0x13, 0xf2, 0xd4, 0xb2, 0x27, 0x16, 0xcf, 0x5c, 0x0c, 0x49, 0x46, 0xc8, 0xc3, 0x15, 0x1d, 0x75, 0xa8, 0x67, 0x88, 0xc8, 0x75, 0x31, 0x6f, 0xf3, 0x92, 0xf0, 0x18, 0xfa, 0xff, 0x0e, 0xa4, 0xd7, 0x92, 0x25, 0x63, 0xca, 0x1f, 0x02, 0xdb, 0x85, 0x79, 0x22, 0x69, 0xc0, 0x35, 0x0d, 0x8d, 0x3a, 0x9a, 0xd0, 0xcc, 0x90, 0xf8, 0x77, 0x28, 0x49, 0x36, 0x79, 0x81, 0xe7, 0x2c, 0xdb, 0x92, 0x96, 0x28, 0x32, 0x0c, 0x9d, 0xf1, 0x7b, 0x88, 0x2a, 0xf8, 0xf6, 0x46, 0x00, 0x4b, 0x9d, 0x42, 0x90, 0xef, 0x16, 0xb4, 0x6a, 0xb8, 0xa1, 0xa3, 0x0d, 0x37, 0x19, 0x06, 0xff, 0x0f, 0xce, 0x50, 0xc3, 0x6d, 0xdb, 0xdd, 0x99, 0xb6, 0x4b, 0x96, 0xb3, 0xc6, 0xc0, 0xde, 0x6b, 0xe8, 0x60, 0x68, 0x77, 0xbd, 0x35, 0xc3, 0xf5, 0x2b, 0xb2, 0x23, 0x72, 0x06, 0x2f, 0x6e, 0x19, 0x29, 0x9b, 0x17, 0x8b, 0xef, 0x3c, 0x4b, 0x0a, 0x2f, 0x8a, 0x76, 0x74, 0xa9, 0x0a, 0x76, 0x33, 0x84, 0x63, 0xe9, 0xf8, 0x92, 0x86, 0x5b, 0x0c, 0x6d, 0x5b, 0xc2, 0xf8, 0x24, 0xf2, 0xd6, 0xa6, 0x31, 0xc3, 0xcd, 0x4d, 0xdf, 0x7c, 0x9e, 0x4b, 0x73, 0x5d, 0x78, 0xbd, 0xc3, 0x1a, 0xfa, 0x18, 0x5a, 0xcf, 0x93, 0xce, 0x15, 0x4c, 0x37, 0x2f, 0x8a, 0x21, 0xe2, 0x42, 0x14, 0x3d, 0x88, 0x29, 0xd6, 0x38, 0x43, 0x6f, 0x2c, 0x9d, 0x29, 0x23, 0x61, 0xc9, 0x2a, 0x5a, 0xd2, 0xf5, 0x92, 0xca, 0xeb, 0xdd, 0xf2, 0x4a, 0xdf, 0x0a, 0x9e, 0x57, 0x4a, 0x13, 0x18, 0x50, 0x9c, 0x83, 0x0c, 0x95, 0xb1, 0x95, 0x49, 0xd5, 0x51, 0x09, 0x0c, 0xe9, 0x18, 0xc6, 0x3d, 0x6a, 0x35, 0x6e, 0x9a, 0xa2, 0x20, 0x95, 0xbb, 0xcb, 0xbc, 0xa5, 0x15, 0xb2, 0x1d, 0x23, 0x3a, 0x1e, 0xe0, 0x21, 0x25, 0x4d, 0xba, 0x93, 0x25, 0x29, 0x26, 0x3c, 0x8f, 0x97, 0x54, 0x0e, 0xe2, 0x2b, 0x93, 0x1a, 0x1e, 0x53, 0x88, 0x65, 0x73, 0x40, 0x56, 0x29, 0x0a, 0x95, 0xa1, 0x2e, 0x43, 0xc5, 0xc9, 0x6e, 0x6f, 0xe5, 0x84, 0xb7, 0xc8, 0x73, 0x36, 0xed, 0x34, 0x64, 0x5c, 0x93, 0xdb, 0x4b, 0xdc, 0xb3, 0xd4, 0xfa, 0x70, 0x33, 0x2c, 0xd7, 0x2d, 0xaa, 0x4e, 0x5b, 0xa6, 0x2c, 0x63, 0x92, 0x21, 0x9a, 0x77, 0x17, 0xe4, 0xf6, 0xea, 0x6a, 0x3a, 0xbf, 0x49, 0x8d, 0x54, 0x50, 0xfb, 0xbe, 0x85, 0xaa, 0x6b, 0x0b, 0x85, 0x9b, 0x39, 0x39, 0x5e, 0x0b, 0xd2, 0xa3, 0x02, 0x27, 0x49, 0x28, 0xc1, 0x4c, 0x65, 0xa4, 0x02, 0x20, 0xbb, 0x0a, 0xb5, 0x53, 0xbb, 0xb8, 0xee, 0x51, 0xc2, 0x52, 0xae, 0x23, 0xc5, 0x47, 0xa9, 0x24, 0x9d, 0x43, 0x52, 0xd0, 0xe6, 0x49, 0x0b, 0x30, 0x74, 0x96, 0x4b, 0x59, 0x60, 0x90, 0x54, 0x9d, 0x7d, 0x2a, 0x83, 0x0c, 0x5d, 0x97, 0xe5, 0xf8, 0xc8, 0x43, 0x50, 0xba, 0x0b, 0x3c, 0x04, 0x06, 0x2a, 0xfe, 0x05, 0x77, 0xdb, 0x33, 0xc5, 0xb4, 0xa5, 0x32, 0xd6, 0x74, 0x36, 0x41, 0x83, 0x2a, 0x06, 0x22, 0xcd, 0x8a, 0xa2, 0x9c, 0x15, 0x2a, 0xe1, 0x45, 0x0d, 0x73, 0xd4, 0x32, 0x17, 0x34, 0x6a, 0xef, 0x30, 0xe9, 0x4e, 0x3b, 0x0e, 0x9d, 0x92, 0x20, 0x91, 0xe8, 0xc6, 0x23, 0xba, 0xb3, 0xd4, 0x13, 0x02, 0x53, 0xb7, 0x16, 0x7d, 0x9f, 0xd0, 0xca, 0xa0, 0x91, 0xd1, 0x58, 0x99, 0xd8, 0x07, 0xfb, 0x4a, 0x93, 0x0a, 0x8c, 0xd2, 0xb7, 0xca, 0xdf, 0xac, 0x42, 0x92, 0xbe, 0x7a, 0x60, 0x40, 0xf7, 0xde, 0x53, 0x1a, 0x23, 0x18, 0x3f, 0x06, 0x27, 0x0e, 0x29, 0xaf, 0x7c, 0x87, 0xb6, 0x8b, 0xda, 0x5d, 0x5c, 0x0d, 0x7f, 0xc3, 0x75, 0xc5, 0xc2, 0x7c, 0x96, 0xa8, 0xff, 0xbf, 0x1a, 0xb5, 0x84, 0x8a, 0xe0, 0x19, 0x9e, 0x1f, 0xe2, 0x3e, 0x23, 0xac, 0x8e, 0x0a, 0x12, 0x07, 0x68, 0x5f, 0x0e, 0xef, 0xa3, 0x73, 0xf6, 0x00, 0x3d, 0xcb, 0x0d, 0xb7, 0xfb, 0xf7, 0x71, 0x27, 0x7b, 0x80, 0xc4, 0x32, 0x89, 0xe9, 0x1f, 0x0d, 0xb7, 0x86, 0x07, 0x42, 0x7b, 0x30, 0xfa, 0xf7, 0x70, 0xff, 0xcb, 0xb1, 0xb2, 0x66, 0x1f, 0xa9, 0x13, 0x5f, 0x2d, 0x1a, 0xd1, 0x89, 0x0e, 0x74, 0xa1, 0x8f, 0xc2, 0x53, 0x4a, 0x47, 0x02, 0x56, 0x4c, 0x60, 0xd2, 0xd7, 0x95, 0x40, 0x0a, 0x2f, 0xc8, 0x67, 0x84, 0xfe, 0x4f, 0x61, 0x9a, 0x18, 0x1a, 0x09, 0xff, 0x12, 0x33, 0x94, 0x84, 0x0e, 0xe2, 0x48, 0xe3, 0x15, 0x29, 0x09, 0xe1, 0xb5, 0xcf, 0x9e, 0xc1, 0xac, 0x1f, 0x73, 0x05, 0x9d, 0xe0, 0x2c, 0xe6, 0x69, 0xde, 0xe0, 0xcf, 0x83, 0x27, 0x1b, 0x0c, 0x7f, 0x00, 0x50, 0x4b, 0x07, 0x08, 0x9e, 0x09, 0x67, 0x19, 0x0c, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x50, 0x4b, 0x01, 0x02, 0x14, 0x00, 0x14, 0x00, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x00, 0x03, 0x9a, 0x57, 0x57, 0x61, 0xd5, 0x4a, 0x60, 0xc0, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc2, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x14, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4d, 0x45, 0x54, 0x41, 0x2d, 0x49, 0x4e, 0x46, 0x2f, 0x4d, 0x41, 0x4e, 0x49, 0x46, 0x45, 0x53, 0x54, 0x2e, 0x4d, 0x46, 0xfe, 0xca, 0x00, 0x00, 0x50, 0x4b, 0x01, 0x02, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x9a, 0x57, 0x57, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4d, 0x45, 0x54, 0x41, 0x2d, 0x49, 0x4e, 0x46, 0x2f, 0x50, 0x4b, 0x01, 0x02, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x9a, 0x57, 0x57, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x2d, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x2f, 0x50, 0x4b, 0x01, 0x02, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x9a, 0x57, 0x57, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4e, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x2f, 0x7a, 0x65, 0x64, 0x69, 0x6b, 0x2f, 0x50, 0x4b, 0x01, 0x02, 0x14, 0x00, 0x14, 0x00, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x00, 0xe4, 0x99, 0x57, 0x57, 0xaf, 0xf7, 0x86, 0xbd, 0x86, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0xe2, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x21, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x75, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x2f, 0x7a, 0x65, 0x64, 0x69, 0x6b, 0x2f, 0x48, 0x61, 0x63, 0x6b, 0x43, 0x6c, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x50, 0x61, 0x74, 0x63, 0x68, 0x65, 0x72, 0x24, 0x31, 0x2e, 0x63, 0x6c, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x50, 0x4b, 0x01, 0x02, 0x14, 0x00, 0x14, 0x00, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x00, 0xe4, 0x99, 0x57, 0x57, 0xcd, 0x1d, 0x0f, 0xa0, 0x58, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x98, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x23, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4a, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x2f, 0x7a, 0x65, 0x64, 0x69, 0x6b, 0x2f, 0x48, 0x61, 0x63, 0x6b, 0x43, 0x6c, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x50, 0x61, 0x74, 0x63, 0x68, 0x65, 0x72, 0x24, 0x31, 0x24, 0x31, 0x2e, 0x63, 0x6c, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x50, 0x4b, 0x01, 0x02, 0x14, 0x00, 0x14, 0x00, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x00, 0xe4, 0x99, 0x57, 0x57, 0x9e, 0x09, 0x67, 0x19, 0x0c, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xf3, 0x07, 0x00, 0x00, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x2f, 0x7a, 0x65, 0x64, 0x69, 0x6b, 0x2f, 0x48, 0x61, 0x63, 0x6b, 0x43, 0x6c, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x50, 0x61, 0x74, 0x63, 0x68, 0x65, 0x72, 0x2e, 0x63, 0x6c, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x50, 0x4b, 0x05, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0x00, 0x07, 0x00, 0xd2, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4c, 0x0b, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}; 
static const int lib_size = sizeof(lib_bytes);
```

What's in the jar file:

```java
package me.zedik;

import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;

public class HackClassPatcher {
    public static void doStuffIdk() {
        Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.capabilities.allowFlying = true;
        System.out.println("hi lol");
    }

    // some other random stuff
}
```

The injection code:

```cpp
// use miniz to extract class files from jar file
void JavaUtils::loadJar(jobject classLoader, const unsigned char *jarBytes, size_t size) {
    mz_zip_archive archive{};
    if (!mz_zip_reader_init_mem(&archive, jarBytes, size, 0)) return;
    mz_uint file_number = mz_zip_reader_get_num_files(&archive);
    for (mz_uint i = 0; i < file_number; i++) {
        if (!mz_zip_reader_is_file_supported(&archive, i)) continue;
        
        char str[256] = {0};
        mz_zip_reader_get_filename(&archive, i, str, 256);
        std::string fileName(str);

        if (fileName.size() <= 6) continue;
        if (fileName.substr(fileName.size() - 6) != ".class") continue;
        
        size_t classBytes_size = 0;
        unsigned char *classBytes = (unsigned char*) mz_zip_reader_extract_to_heap(&archive, i, &classBytes_size, 0);
        if (!classBytes) {
            mz_zip_reader_end(&archive);
            return;
        }
        
        jclass jaclass = client->env->DefineClass(nullptr, classLoader, (const jbyte*) classBytes, (jsize) classBytes_size);
        if (jaclass) client->env->DeleteLocalRef(jaclass);
        mz_free(classBytes);
    }
    mz_zip_reader_end(&archive);
}

// creates a new class loader to load the injected classes
jobject JavaUtils::newClassLoader() {
    jclass urlClass = client->env->FindClass("java/net/URL");
    jobjectArray urls = client->env->NewObjectArray(0, urlClass, nullptr);
    jclass URLClassLoaderClass = client->env->FindClass("java/net/URLClassLoader");
    jmethodID URLClassLoaderContructor = client->env->GetMethodID(URLClassLoaderClass, "<init>", "([Ljava/net/URL;)V");
    jobject URLClassLoader = client->env->NewObject(URLClassLoaderClass, URLClassLoaderContructor, urls);

    client->env->DeleteLocalRef(urlClass);
    client->env->DeleteLocalRef(urls);
    client->env->DeleteLocalRef(URLClassLoaderClass);

    return URLClassLoader;
}
```

Where I inject the jar:

```cpp
jobject classLoader = JavaUtils::newClassLoader();
JavaUtils::loadJar(classLoader, lib_bytes, lib_size);
```

Calling the method:

```cpp
jclass libClass = client->getClass("me.zedik.HackClassPatcher");
        if (libClass == nullptr) {
            std::cout << "hack patcher class not found" << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        jmethodID libMethod = client->env->GetStaticMethodID(libClass, "doStuffIdk", "()V");
        if (libMethod == nullptr) {
            std::cout << "hack method not found" << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        client->env->CallStaticVoidMethod(libClass, libMethod);
        std::cout << "success" << std::endl;

        if (client->env->ExceptionCheck() == JNI_TRUE) {
            std::cout << "EXCEPTION" << std::endl;
            jthrowable exception = client->env->ExceptionOccurred();
            client->env->ExceptionClear();

            JavaUtils::getInformation(exception); // prints stack trace
            return;
        }
```

Output:

```
EXCEPTION:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/minecraft/client/Minecraft
    me.zedik.HackClassPatcher.doStuffIdk(HackClassPatcher.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.minecraft.client.Minecraft
    java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    me.zedik.HackClassPatcher.doStuffIdk(HackClassPatcher.java:8)
```

`net/minecraft/client/Minecraft` is not included in the jar file but is included in the parent process.

Comment: calling from c++ via jni, the constructed class loader is deleted after the scope exits (or at least that is what i think is the issue here). call NewGlobalRef on the constructed class loader, and return the return value of that function

Comment: additionally: i am assuming you're calling loadClass on your custom class loader when using client.getClass. does that class loader know about the other class loaders, so it can delegate in case of not finding a class? (mainly application and boot class loader)

Comment: @0x150 I think that's it. Does the class loader need to know about other class loaders and how do you make it do that? Also, I'm not calling loadClass. I'm using env->DefineClass.

Comment: Only that classloader knows about the injected class. You need to set that class loader as the thread context class loader. NB if `FindClass()` and friends return null there is a pending Java exception ...

Comment: @0x150 How do you get the thread context class loader in JNI? Or is there a way for it to work to use my current class loader?

Comment: I think you would have to do it in Java. It would be easier to define the classloader from there anyway.

Comment: @user207421 But all of this has to be done in the JNI, because I don't have access to the process code.

Comment: `java.lang.ClassLoader#getSystemClassLoader`? Alternatively enumerate all threads and check their context class loader.

Comment: Well you would have to call `Thread.setContextClassLoader()` or whatever it is from JNI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to 0x150 I found a solution for anyone who has the same problem.
Just get the classloader from a random class.

```cpp
jobject JavaUtils::getClassLoader() {
    std::cout << "Getting class loader" << std::endl;
    jclass classClass = client->getClass("java.lang.Class");
    jclass mcClass = client->getClass("net.minecraft.client.Minecraft");
    jmethodID getClassLoader = client->env->GetMethodID(classClass, "getClassLoader", "()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;");
    jobject classLoader = client->env->CallObjectMethod(mcClass, getClassLoader);

    return classLoader;
}
```